# Velocity template function from string literal

Tags: velocity

Is it possible to call a function that was created from string literal? For example

```
${object}.staticPartOfFunctionName${dynamicPartOfFunctionName}()
```

doesn't return correct value, but instead just prints the object and the function name.

```
 $object.staticFunctionName()
```

prints correctly, and

```
 $object.staticPartOfFunctionName${dynamicPartOfFunctionName}()
```

gives warning "Encountered ")"

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use introspection:

```
#evaluate("\$object.staticPartOfFunctionName${dynamicPartOfFunctionName}()")
```

Comment: Can you explain more what this does? It works only if static part is written as a string literal. Also, if I put it inside #set or #if, it doesn't work. What is the role of \?

Comment: If the static part is not a string literal, it's not static so you'll have to write something like `${myDynamicPrefix}` instead of `staticPartOfFunctionName`. It should also work with `#if` or `#set`, please post your code. The \ is here to **escape** the dollar sign. Basically, you are building a Velocity expression before passing it to the `#evaluate` directive (you are performing a two-steps evaluation, you need to escape the dollar sign for it to reach the second evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found one solution myself from Java side:

`$object.getClass().getMethod("staticPartOfFunctionName$dynamicPartOfFunctionName").invoke($object))`

I don't know if it's any good, so if someone knows how to do it velocity way, lemme know.